# IIS - PHP page load only after reloading 2-3 times

Tags: php, css, iis, fastcgi, windows-server-2016

So i have this page setup for my private game server. I host the game server and web on the same dedicated server running windows server 2016. I use IIS to host the website. Right now am facing a problem, page only loads after reloading for 2-3 times. Till then it returns HTTP error 500. Once the page is loaded, i have to refresh multiple times to load each content. What is going on ?

Page -> www.ram-sro.com

Index.php

```
<?php
    include("_incl/config.inc.php");
    $sec = new Security();
    $conf = new Config();
    $mssql = new mssql();
    $mssql->dbOpen($conf->accountDbName);
    $modDir = "mod/";
    $modExt = ".php";
    session_start();
?>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title><?php echo "$conf->siteName" ?></title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $conf->description; ?>" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $conf->keywords; ?>" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
            function clearText(formfield){
                if (formfield.defaultValue==formfield.value) {
                    formfield.value = ""
                }
            }
            -->
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <div id="page-body">
                <div class="page-body topbox">
                    <div class="page-body blackspace"></div>
                    <div class="page-body topbox-content">
                        <div class="topbox-webtitle">
                        </div>
                        <div class="topbox-user">
                            <div class="social-networks">
                                <a href="<?php echo $conf->facebook;?>"><img src="img/fb-icon.png" width="40px" height="40px;" alt="Visit us at facebook!" /></a>
                                <a href="<?php echo $conf->twitter;?>"><img src="img/tw-icon.png" width="40px" height="40px;" alt="Visit us at twitter!" /></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form">  
                                <?php include($modDir."user".$modExt);?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="page-body spacer"></div>
                <div class="page-body menubox">
                    <div class="menubox-content">
                        <div id="menubar">
                            <ul>
                                <?php
                                    include($modDir."menu".$modExt);
                                ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="page-body spacer"></div>
                <div class="page-body content">
                    <div class="page-body leftblock">
                        <?php 
                            include($modDir."page".$modExt);
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="page-body rightblock">
                        <?php
                            include($modDir."social".$modExt);
                        ?>
                        <div class="page-body spacer"></div>
                        <div class="page-body info">
                            <?php
                                include($modDir."info".$modExt);
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```